# Change parent link colour when hover child link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do this with CSS.

When I hover `Customize` or `Widgets`, I'd like the parent link (`Dashboard`) to have the red bg/white text styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/oxyns6w7/

```css
.ab-item:hover {
    background:red;
    color:white
}

.ab-submenu li a:hover {
    background:green;
    color:white
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard-links" class="bp_components">
    <ul>
  <li class="menupop">
   <a class="ab-item" href="/wordpress/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>
   <div class="ab-sub-wrapper">
    <ul class="ab-submenu">
     <li>
                        <a href="/wordpress/wp-admin/customize.php">Customize</a>
                        <a href="/wordpress/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </li>  
    </ul>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look on this: http://jsfiddle.net/oxyns6w7/1/ Its solved with Jquery

Comment: Is there a non-jQuery way of achieving this?

Comment: There is a way using selectors, so just check the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector